# How would I classify SAN loss due to Chemically-Induced Fear in Delta Green?

Tags: sanity, medicine-and-drugs, delta-green-rpg

As a relatively-new GM, I've been looking through the Delta Green Agent's Handbook (the new system, not the CoC system), though I unfortunately don't own the Handler's Guide, and I've decided to modify the Last Things Last mission to be the "intro" mission for the Agents.

One of their (multiple) enemies will be a rival organization composed of DG and MJ-12 Renegades, some of whom went Private and now have large corporate holdings, and others who occupy various other positions within the blacker parts of the government, including double agents within official DG itself. Their goals are to get revenge upon Delta Green as well as creating a more Fascist-Corporatist government (think Brave New World). Their rationale differs, but it is attractive to some in DG because it allows for more easy monitoring of citizens and potential outbreaks of the Supernatural; but it is against the Official Delta Green Special Access Program in that this organization wants to research and harness the Unnatural, something which DG takes a Hardline stance against. For those of you who've read The Laundry Files, think of something like the Black Chamber: constantly experimenting with things they cannot hope to understand or control.

This group will use Fear-inducing Chemicals sourced from human pheromones; hormone-like synthetic compounds; and catechol-O-methyl transferase inhibitors, monoamine oxidase inhibitors, and 11 beta hydroxysteroid dehydrogenase type 2 inhibitors. **These are enzymes that break-down stress hormones; inhibiting their production causes the body to have too many stress hormones.**

Long story short, the chemical stimulates stress-hormone production and reduces the body's ability to destroy stress-hormones, and the group uses this to gaslight their opponents. The group encounters traces of it being used in Clyde Baughman's apartment (though they don't know it at the time), and one event in particular is supposed to threaten SAN when combined with the effects of the drug (0/1). The effects of the actual drug are actually much worse when concentrated or exposed for prolong periods of time.

Should I rule this as "Helplessness" and treat it that way for the purposes of Adaptation, or should I rule it as a separate category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helplessness seems to be a good fit.

The three categories are Violence, Helplessness, and Unnatural.

By the process of elimination; the use of the chemical isn't Unnatural and the question doesn't seem to indicate that the chemical would be delivered in a violent manner.

Someone under the influence of a mind-altering chemical would be helpless to resist this induced fear. The game mechanics offer someone to become 'Adjusted' to Helplessness SAN loss - which could be explained by the body developing a tolerance to the chemicals.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Thanks for the prompt - I've added a little more. Although the question was a couple of hundred words, ultimately it was asking for a yes/no answer. But I understand the community benefits from a justification.

Comment: This looks good to me now, thanks for expanding it!